# checkinstall asking for version

Tags: package-management, checkinstall, autotools

I have a autoconf/automake/autoeverything project that I'm installing with checkinstall.  When I go to install it, I'm shown this

```
This package will be built according to these values: 

0 -  Maintainer: [ brooks94@foo.com ]
1 -  Summary: [ Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2 ]
2 -  Name:    [ mypkg ]
3 -  Version: [  ]
4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
5 -  License: [ GPL ]
6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
7 -  Architecture: [ amd64 ]
8 -  Source location: [ mypkg ]
9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
10 - Requires: [  ]
11 - Provides: [ mypkg ]
12 - Conflicts: [  ]
13 - Replaces: [  ]
```

... which generally looks good, but has a missing "version".  Check install won't proceed until I manually give it a value.  My question is, in what file can I put that version so that I don't need to manually enter it ever time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I think I figured this out.  It will try the following:

- Use anything after '-' in the name of the current directory.  That is, naming the directory 'project-1.0' will give it a value of '1.0'.  My directory was simply named 'project'.
- Second it will look for a line '#define VERSION "something"' in config.log, and give it a value of 'something'.  I still don't know why my config.log doesn't have that line in it.
- If the config.log file doesn't exist, it will use the current date.

In my case, because config.log does exist, but was missing the '#define VERSION' line, it was simply getting no value at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can also provide version to checkinstall via `--pkgversion` flag. Example:

```
checkinstall --pkgversion="1.2"
```